Deploy Angular Project and not use https
I need deploy an Angular App and use "http://:/api/" instead "https://:/api/", that App will be deploy in Hostinger.
I have in envimorent.prod.ts:
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  empresa: 'Title of page',
  blnOcultarWarnings: false,
  apiURL: "http://<public ip>:<port>/",
};

Some help? Thanks in advance.

If you are running the angular application in HTTP and you can API using HTTP (given that is exposed in HTTP - Which is not secure). Calling HTTPS in HTTP application will be blocked by the browser

If you are using webserver to server static HTML files like nginx, then you should use proxy_pass.
JS can not make cross-browser requests by itself because of security restrictions.
